# PHP Laravel PDO MSSQL Data Source Name Not Found on Mac OS

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, laravel-8

I'am currently trying to connect on MSSQL server using the sqlsrv driver of the laravel 8 and its default connection is using PDO MSSQL, I already manage to connect using sqlsrv only and the driver is already loaded in the php info but the PDO MSSQL still encounter the following error in the laravel 8 framework.
[image]

[image]
[image]

I already install the odbc using this instructions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos
Below is the odbcinst.ini and for my odbc.ini it is empty

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by editing the odbc.ini in both user and system settings the path are below:
System = `/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`
User = `~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini`

Then the Laravel PDO Driver read the Data source,

[image]